# AWS Lambda to Azure function migration

Tags: aws-lambda, azure-functions

I have an existing AWS Lambda function written in JAVA. As part of migration to Azure, I need to migrate AWS Lambda function into Azure function. Except rewriting that lengthy Lambda function(to make it compatible with Azure Function), is there any easy way to migrate it in Azure Function?

Answer (score 2):

this is Francisco from the Azure Functions team. At the present time, we do not have any migration tools. However, to get you started, please take a look at our programming model at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-java-maven. Please do not hesitate to reach out to us with any questions you might have.